# Automating Pagination using selenium C#

Tags: java, c#, selenium, automation, pagination

Trying to automate the pagination and get the total number of records available at the end of the page.

**I have tried below till now**

```java
public int getTotalNumberOfRows() {

    var clickOnNextButton = pageNavigationElement();// clicking on the next arrow key

    var numberOfPages = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@aria-label]")); //number of pages available like 1 to 7 in my case

    int count = 0; // initializing the count
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfPages.Count - 1; i++) {
        var rowsOnPages = verifyPaginationOnSelectedPage(); // 10 rows available in a page
        foreach (var rows in rowsOnPages) {
            count++;
        }
        clickOnNextButton.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now the problem is I am able to iterate till the last page, getting the total number of records also but as soon as I reached the last page code is again trying to click on next button which is disabled.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: @MHUPTA check the button status (In HTML) before clicking on the Next button if Status of the button is disabled then break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to check if pageNavigationElement is disabled. Assuming at the last page your arrow will have a class "disabled" you can do something like this:

```
public boolean checkNavigationElementIsDisabled() {
    var elClass = pageNavigationElement().getAttribute("class");
    if (elClass.contains("disabled") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, add the controll

```
public int getTotalNumberOfRows() {

    var clickOnNextButton = pageNavigationElement();// clicking on the next arrow key

    var numberOfPages = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@aria-label]")); //number of pages available like 1 to 7 in my case

    int count = 0; // initializing the count
    while (!checkNavigationElementIsDisabled()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfPages.Count - 1; i++) {
        var rowsOnPages = verifyPaginationOnSelectedPage(); // 10 rows available in a page
        foreach (var rows in rowsOnPages) {
            count++;
        }
        clickOnNextButton.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside foreach loop is not required. You can try this bellow code, hope it will work. Locator class name I am assuming. I have tried to optimize the code.

```cs
// assuming next button class name is "next_button" or use id 

int count = 0; // initializing the count
while(_driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("next_button")).Enabled){
    int rowscount = _driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("rows-class-name")).FirstOrDefault(ele => ele.Displayed).Count();// Assume class name "rows-class-name"
    if(rowsCount <= 10){
        count += rowsCount;
    }
    else{
        Assert.Fail("In DOM more than 10rows are visible");
    }
    _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("next_button")).Click();
    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
}
```

Then you can return count or print it.